# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I am getting this error from last week, earlier it was working well.
I have attached screenshot of this error.I am using app engine for android project.Please let me know possible suggestion to solve the issue.[image]

Appengine logs 
[image]

Comment: 500 errors will come from server side code mistakes. use exception handling

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae where exactly should  i use exception handling in my project ?

Comment: Ahmed see this https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Exception.html

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae I know about exceptions where should i use this exception handler in order to get complete detailed error log?

Comment: write your entire json code in try block, in catch block you can get the exception

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae Actually you are not understanding my problem statement. Let me elaborate a little the thing is i have models and created api endpoints for those models after deploying on appengine when i visit xxxx.appspot.com i get this issue.I do not have any json code.

Comment: A couple details you may want to add to clarify this question: (1) is this an Endpoints v1 or v2 API? (2) Are you using Endpoints frameworks or just the Endpoints platform? (3) Check your AppEngine logs in your Google Cloud Console project and see if it gives any more detail about this 500.

Comment: @John I am using v1 api with Endpoints platform.And edited my question with appengine logs

Comment: Please post the contents of your `web.xml`.